# github action expressions - split string

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to use a part of current branch name as a tag for publishing docker image in CI pipeline. The problem is that in my org, there is a convention to name branches like `feature/foo`, and docker tags can't contain slashes. So I want to split the string on '/' symbol and take the last part.

The full branch name, with slashes, should be in variable `github.ref_name`. Here is the expression I'm trying to evaluate: `${{ github.ref_name.split('/')[-1]  }}`.

I get this error: `Unable to interpolate expression 'format('{0}', github.ref_name.split('/')[-1])': Failed to parse: unexpected token "(" while parsing arguments of function call. expecting ",", ")"`

What are the options for manipulating strings in github actions expression? I didn't find it in docs https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions

Comment: You could eventually perform that split operation in a previous job (using shell commands) and save the value as output, before manipulating it in a second job expression. That would make it easier to debug / log as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## IMPROVED:

This technique doesn't need to bring in anything from the actions marketplace.

Add this to `steps:` in an action:

```yaml
      - name: Split branch name
        env:
          BRANCH: ${{ github.ref_name }}
        id: split
        run: echo "::set-output name=fragment::${BRANCH##*/}"
```

It captures the output of a shell command. The only necessary actions are setting `github.ref_name` to an environmental variable and using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#:%7E:text=the%20last%20element.-,%24%7Bparameter%23word%7D,the%20array%20in%20turn%2C%20and%20the%20expansion%20is%20the%20resultant%20list.,-%24%7Bparameter/) to get the part of the branch name you want.

- `##` greedily removes the subsequent pattern off the front
- `*/` matches anything followed by a `/`
- So, `##*/` removes everything up to and including the final forward slash.

Because `id` is `split`, and `name=fragment`, you then reference your split string with `steps.split.outputs.fragment`. For example,

```yaml
      # Another step
      - name: Test variable
        run: |
          echo ${{ steps.split.outputs.fragment }}
```

Other parameter expansion features would be useful here, like `#`, `%`, and `%%` in addition to `##`.

#### 220829: Final update

Originally I spawned another process with `$(echo ${BRANCH##*/})` but that is unnecessary. The variable can be directly referenced.

---

## ORIGINAL:

I'm doing something essentially the same and using an action was the easiest temporary workaround, however I also would have preferred something built-in like a string-splitting expression. For now here is what worked.

```yaml
      - uses: jungwinter/split@master
        id: branch
        with:
          msg: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          separator: "/"
          maxsplit: -1
```

From its repo:

> **Outputs**
>
> - `_0`, `_1`, ..., `_n`: Each result of a split
>
>   - According to metadata syntax of outputs, it has `_` prefix
>   - Currently, support only 100 splits
> - `length`: Length of the splits

So, then I can reference each portion of the string with `steps.branch.outputs._n`, with `branch` being the id and `n` being the split index.

I was looking for the first instead of the last value in the branch name, so I could set `maxsplit` to 1 and just take `_0`. In your case you might need to do some magic with checking `length` and choosing the index from there.

Comment: I need last element, is -1 index supported?

Comment: It doesn't look like it based on the code, but I just tested another way and it works very well. I will add it to the original post

Comment: You could simplify this even further, since the value of github.ref_name is also present in the environment variable GITHUB_REF_NAME, so you don't need to create a new environment variable to get that value.

Comment: I like the original solution, with the updated version how do I get the 1st, 2nd.... split values?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using bash to do the split and publishing it as job output. In the retrospect should have went for just installing python (bash syntax is way more confusing and less maintainable).

```yaml
  build-docker:
    container: docker:cli
    outputs:
      docker-tag: ${{steps.docker-tag.outputs.DOCKER_TAG}}
    steps:
      - name: add bash
        run: |
          apk update
          apk upgrade
          apk add bash
        
      - name: determine docker tag by splitting branch name on slash
        id: docker-tag
        shell: bash
        run: |
          split=(${GITHUB_REF_NAME//\// })
          index=$((${#split[@]}-1))
          DOCKER_TAG=${split[$index]}
          echo DOCKER_TAG=$DOCKER_TAG >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "::set-output name=DOCKER_TAG::$DOCKER_TAG"

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
          file: ./docker/ci/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: |
            artifactory.com/repo/image:${{ env.DOCKER_TAG }}
          

  test-job:
    needs: build-docker
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Linux, docker]
    container:
      image: artifactory.com/repo/image:${{ needs.build-docker.outputs.docker-tag }}
```